# exception raised if not enough space on hdd when saving FileField

Tags: django, file-upload, exception, upload

What will happen if server hard drive is nearly full **OR** it's memory is full, when I try to upload a (huge) file and save it to my model `FileField`?

Will Django raise an exception? What type it is? Is it a subclass of `DatabaseError`?

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation that describes this case, so it's likely going to throw `IOError` which is the python error that is raised when reading or writing fails.

Comment: @user2896976: yeah I cannot find anything too. So even if it is about memory (not hdd), it is also `IOError`?

Comment: You shouldn't run into memory problems because FileField will save the file in chunks. It will only read 64KB at a time. If you're running into memory issues at that point you need to expand your server hardware.